# Use of SpeechRecognizer produces ERROR_NETWORK (Value 2)

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am using  the class SpeechRecognizer by calling the method startListening when a button is pressed, but I get an error. First the callback methods onReadyForSpeech, onBeginningOfSpeech, onEndofSpeech are called (immediately) and at the end onError with the errorcode 2 "ERROR_NETWORK" is called. When I call the intent directly by using startActivityForResult, it works. But I want to get rid of the time consuming popup dialog.
I have the RECORD_AUDIO permission set.

I am not sure, but perhaps the intent want to load something from the internet. For that, I tried to add the INTERNET-Permission, but it did not work either.

Here the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements RecognitionListener
{   
    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;

    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
    {
        AddLog("onReadyForSpeech called.");
    }

    public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
    {
        AddLog("onBeginningOfSpeech called.");
    }

    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
    {
        AddLog("onRmsChanged called.");
    }

    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
    {
        AddLog("onBufferReceived called.");
    }

    public void onEndOfSpeech()
    {
        AddLog("onEndOfSpeech called.");
    }

    public void onError(int error)
    {
        AddLog(String.format("onError called with id: %d.", error));
    }

    public void onResults(Bundle results)
    {
        String str = new String();
        ArrayList<String> data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            str += data.get(i);
        }

        final String strAnswer = str;

        AddLog(String.format("Answer is %s", strAnswer));
    }

    public void onPartialResults(Bundle psrtialResults)
    {
        AddLog("onPartialResults called.");
    }

    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
    {
        AddLog("onEvent called.");
    }           

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);        
        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
    {
        public PlaceholderFragment()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public void AddLog(final String text)
    {
        TextView txtLogView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLog);
        if (txtLogView != null)
        {
            txtLogView.append(text + "\n");
        }
    }

    // Only for test    
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            AddLog(matches.get(0));
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void Start(View view)
    {
        AddLog("Start pressed.");

        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");

        // Only for test
        //startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);

        AddLog("startListening called.");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Is it possible, that the recognizer wants to load a missing language pack?

Comment: I had a look in the source code ([link](http://hi-android.info/src/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.java.html)`code`. I can not see, that ERROR_NETWORK is set here.

Comment: You probably want to call Start method from UI thread, is there something like that?

Comment: In my opinion the startListening call is done in the UI thread already (because Start is an on_click handler from a button).

Comment: My problem is, that RecognitionListener does not work correct. It calls onError with the error code 2.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by myself. The problem was, that the language pack for US had an update. I had to load it by hand (in the language settings of my mobile). After that the error ERROR_NETWORK disappeared.

Comment: Seems unrelated. Language pack is for **offline** recognition.